# Can SDKMAN set random environment variables?

Tags: sdkman

Besides selecting the versions of various tools I want to have project-specific settings for things like PGUSER.  Is there a way to make `sdk env` set miscellaneous environment variables like that?

I didn't see anything generic in `sdk list` or in the documentation.